# pass user' choice into repository variable in Oracle BI EE

Tags: business-intelligence, obiee

My need is to pass user' choice into repository variable in Oracle Business Intelligence (OBIEE). Query does work good with default values of variable. Don't know how to pass parameter from Analysis prompt into repository variable. Please help.

Comment: can see result in repository, but Analysis gives error: Odbc driver returned an error (SQLExecDirectW).
Error Details
Error Codes: OPR4ONWY:U9IM8TAC:OI2DL65P
State: HY000. Code: 10058. [NQODBC] [SQL_STATE: HY000] [nQSError: 10058] A general error has occurred. [nQSError: 43113] Message returned from OBIS. [nQSError: 43119] Query Failed: [nQSError: 17001] Oracle Error code: 1722, message: ORA-01722: invalid number at OCI call OCIStmtFetch. [nQSError: 17012] Bulk fetch failed. (HY000)
SQL Issued: SELECT 0 s_0, "VOLKSBANK"."cash_limits"."ACCNAME" s_1 FROM "VOLKSBANK" FETCH FIRST 2000001 ROWS ONLY

Comment: It seems to me that parameter is not passed from Analysis into repository. I think so because when I try to pass characters instead of numbers to my pipelined function I got the same error: select * from table(ORACLEBI.PKG_CASH_LIMITS.FN_B2EXPORT('d','t')) *
Error at line 1
ORA-01722: invalid number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't populate a repository variable directly from a Dashboard, as a repository variable is the same constant for all users. You could use a presentation variable, populated from a Dashboard Prompt to provide similar functionality though. Nico has an [overview of Presentations Variables](http://gerardnico.com/wiki/dat/obiee/presentation_variable) on his site.

Comment: jackohug, well, I use this decision at a moment: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?forumID=378&threadID=2475813 (see post 19/12/2012 10:07). I don't like it, but it works.